# How to require arguments in argparse and make them non-positional?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python script where I would like to force all required arguments to be named (non-positional).

So the following should work:

`python myscript --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2
 python myscript --arg2 arg2 --arg1 arg1`

But the following should fail:

`python myscript arg1 arg2
 python myscript --madeUpArg arg1 --arg2 arg2`

From what I can tell, in argparse if you make something required, it becomes a positional argument, so both of the second examples that I want to fail will succeed (even the second case, with the made up argument!). How do I get desired functionality?

Comment: I'd point out that there's a somewhat common convention that required arguments should be positional, and switches (the ones with dashes like `--arg1`) should be optional. Not to say you have to do it that way, but just be aware that you'll be throwing some people a curveball, so to speak - they may not expect the program to require non-positional arguments.

Comment: This  `required` paragraph doesn't say it becomes a `positional`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required.  Have you experimented with the `required` parameter?

Comment: Use an `argument_group` https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups, if you don't like how the `help` labels your required named arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No argument you haven't defined will be accepted as long as you don't call `parse_known_args` explicitly.

To make an otherwise optional argument required, use the `required` keyword argument when defining it.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--arg1", required=True)
p.add_argument("--arg2", required=True)
```

Comment: I realized that part of what was confusing me is that the argument parser will by default accept any unambiguous prefix for an argument. E.g. if you have just one argument `--arg1` it will accept `--ar`. This made me think it was not properly requiring the arguments.

Comment: hmmmm.... the 3 lines above look ok but what are you using to parse the arguments (ie. parser.parse_args? pparser.parse_intermixed_args? )?

Comment: I'm assuming basic familiarity with how `argparse` works: `args = p.parse_args()`.